# Software [CMS] for PTA websites?

Tags: content-management-system

I'm looking for [preferably free] software that's designed to support Parent Teacher Association websites.  CMS seem like the right place to start.  I'm sure many of them could be customized to support our needs (member registration, forums, document sharing, photos, bulk emailing, online payment processing) but I'm wondering if there are any specialized PTA software packages already out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is always a good first bet, with modules for everything you've just described. You can also take a look at [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/). Some say they find Joomla easier to manage.

Drupal is very common and there are [lots of options for hosting](http://drupal.org/hosting). Depending on how elaborate you want to get, it's easy to hire [someone to set it up for you as well](http://drupal.org/drupal-services).

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options:

Drupal

Joomla

Dotnetnuke